# Modern symbolic execution techniques

Tags: testing, verification, symbolic-execution

What is the best technique of symbolic execution?
Would you please help me to find pure symbolic execution and pure concolic testing tool (I mean, e.g. it is not including model checking,etc.) with its source?

Answer (score 2):

Concolic Testing Tools:

- CREST for C[Open Source]
- CATG for JAVA
- Jalangi for javascript [Open Source]
- Microsoft PEX for .Net framework [power tool in Visual Studio]
- CutEr for Erlang functional programming [Open Source]

For Symbolic Execution, several tools are listed on the link below(Some tools are common, because they have option for both):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution